# Android: Can't launch intent from button

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

So, my app is simple, in the mainscreen I should click a button which is gonna launch another activity with tabs, but once I click the button, the activity doesn't launch, and I get the error: Source Not Found with this log:

```
Thread [<3> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
    <VM does not provide monitor information>   
    ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2503  
    ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2519   
    ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 123 
    ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1870  
    ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
    Looper.loop() line: 123 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4370    
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521  
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 868  
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 626 
    NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Here is the mainActivity : Bienvenue.java:

```
public class Bienvenue extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bienvenue);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
             // here i call new screen;
             Intent i = new Intent(Bienvenue.this, Histoire.class);
             startActivity(i);
             } 
    });

}
```

Here is a part of the manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".Splash" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.category.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Bienvenue" android:exported="false" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.maghribouna.amine.ters.Bienvenue" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Histoire" android:exported="false" android:label="@string/app_name">

    </activity>
```

I don't see a reason to add the other codes, so the error must figure in these!

Comment: Is there more to the LogCat? Please post all of the red lines and your relevant code.

Comment: Even add the code along with that, if you can.

Comment: put all your logcat stack . have you declared your secondActivity in the Manifest File ?

Comment: Yes I did, with the intents

Comment: @AmineTers : Put your Code and the logCat with Red Color ( Exceptions )

Comment: Pasting here your code could help

Comment: @AmineTers : i think this is second time you are asking same question but both time you have not provided full information

Comment: @AmineTers : code looking f9 try to run after Cleaning it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem

```
<activity android:name=".Splash" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.category.MAIN" />



   **<category android:name="android.intent.category.LUNCHER" />**


  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

It's

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
             // Launcher!
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Comment: Still not working, the problem is not with this activity, it's with Histoire.java or Bienvenue.java

Comment: It's not luncher my mate, it's LAUNCHER. Just change the lines I had posted in your manifest file. I guess that would do the thing.

Comment: evenif :( ! the problem, is when I click on the button, instead of getting the activity Histoire.java, I get simply the error log, and the app crashes !

Comment: try this, remove this code from your manifest file and see if it works.<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.maghribouna.amine.ters.Bienvenue" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

Answer (score 0):

```
final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonIdName);
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class));
    }
});
```

This is the code I use to switch activities. Your button needs to use the ID set in your activity's layout xml (which is then referenced in R.java). If your button ID is "buttonStart", then make sure the findViewById() uses that name.

If your issue is deeper than that, some code would be great.

Edit: Try this:

```
public class Bienvenue extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bienvenue);

    final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Bienvenue.this, Histoire.class));
        } 
    });

}
```